# Bash: How to edit multiple json files while incrementing a field globally?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have multiple json files in subfolders, each containing an array of objects with same keys, different values.
example: **file1.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mary"
    }
]
```

**file2.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "mulberry"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "strawberry"
    }
]
```

...

I want to globally increment the value of "id" on all files without resetting the number between files.

What I have here works but it only increments each file locally and resets the counter on next file. What I want is to increment id for all files, so say if one combines two separate files, the id fields will remain unique and numeric.

Expected result:

**file1.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Mary"
    }
]
```

**file2.json:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "mulberry"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "strawberry"
    }
]
```

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
grep -rl --exclude=${0:2} . -e '"id":' | while read -r file; do
    echo "\nEditing: $file\n"
    jq 'to_entries | map(.value["id"] = '"$i"') | map(.value)' $file
    ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The following avoids having to call jq more than once, but results in the files being populated with "compact" JSON:

```
jq -nrc '
   def resetId($start):
     . as $in | [range(0; length) as $i | $in[$i] | .id = $start + $i];
   foreach inputs as $file ({n:1};
     .n as $n
     | .emit = [input_filename, ($file | resetId($n))]
     | .n += ($file|length) )
  | .emit[] ' file1.json file2.json | 
  awk ' NR%2==1 { fn=$1; next} {print $1 > fn}'
```

Note that this will overwrite the files, so you might want to tweak the last line to avoid that.

If you want to use the above approach but have the JSON pretty-printed in each output file, you could call jq on each resultant file.  This requires fewer calls to jq than the obvious alternative, namely for each file, calling jq to determine the array length, and then again to perform the update.

Yet another (rather messy) option would be to call jq once to determine the array sizes, and then for each file calling jq again.

Comment: Thank you for replying @peak. Your code simply changes the value of "id" to 1 on all files  and write that to the file. No incrementing. Imagine hundreds of files with different/non-sequential names and I only want to edit the contents of files, changing value of a key and keeping the rest as-is.

Here is the version with your suggestion:
```

Comment: I’ve tested the proposed solution and it works, so evidently you’re doing something wrong.

Comment: This is what I did. Put yours into the original code:
`#!/bin/bash
i=0
grep -rl --exclude=${0:2} . -e '"id":' | while read -r file; do
    echo "\nEditing: $file\n"

    jq -nrc '
   def resetId($start):
     . as $in | [range(0; length) as $i | $in[$i] | .id = $start + $i];
   foreach inputs as $file ({n:1};
     .n as $n
     | .emit = [input_filename, ($file | resetId($n))]
     | .n += ($file|length) )
  | .emit[] ' $file | 
  awk ' NR%2==1 { fn=$1; next} {print $1 > fn}'
    ((i++))
done`
(Sorry for the line breaks)

Comment: @QAscoop Peak's approach is not supposed to be run in a loop (you are using `while`) with one file per iteration, but instead of it, providing all files as arguments to jq at once (see the `file1.json file2.json` part). For each, it generates one filename and one line of new content, and the subsequent awk script then loops over them, taking care of storing the contents into the corresponding files (see `print $1 > fn`). In order to keep your initial file filters (`grep`), you could replace your `while` loop, viz. prefix the jq call with `xargs  -d'\n'` or similar.

Comment: I posted the working sample. Let me know if anything is wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

This solution redirects output from jq to temp file before overwriting original file, works: `jq --argjson id $start_id '.[] |= . + {"id": ($id + (.id-1))}' "$file" > tmp.json && mv tmp.json "$file"`

Final code hardcodes the length of array to avoid the mess @peak mentioned at the end of his proposal:

```
#!/bin/bash
start_id=1
find . -type f -name '*.json' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    echo "Updating $file"
    jq --argjson id $start_id '.[] |= . + {"id": ($id + (.id-1))}' "$file" > tmp.json && mv tmp.json "$file"
    echo "Updated $file with start_id=$start_id"
    start_id=$((start_id + 10))
done
```

This script updates JSON files in current directory and updates "id" field to each JSON object in the file. The script uses the `find` command to locate all the .JSON files in the current directory and its subdirectories.

Here is a line-by-line explanation of the script:

1. `#!/bin/bash`: This is the shebang line that specifies the interpreter to use when executing the script. In this case, it specifies that the Bash shell should be used.
2. `start_id=1`: This initializes the variable `start_id` to 1. This variable is used to assign values to the "id" field in each JSON object.
3. `find . -type f -name '*.json' -print0`: This uses the `find` command to locate all files with a `.json` extension in the current directory and its subdirectories. The `-type f` option specifies that only regular files should be included in the search, and the `-name '*.json'` option specifies that the files should have a `.json` extension. The `-print0` option separates the file names with a null character instead of a newline.
4. `while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do`: This starts a loop that reads the null-separated file names from `find` into the variable `file`.
5. `echo "Updating $file"`: This displays a message indicating the file that is being updated.
6. `jq --argjson id $start_id '.[] |= . + {"id": ($id + (.id-1))}' "$file" > tmp.json && mv tmp.json "$file"`: This uses the `jq` command to update the JSON file. The `--argjson` option passes the value of the `start_id` variable to `jq` as a JSON argument named `id`. The `jq` expression updates each JSON object in the file by adding an "id" field with a value that is calculated based on the previous object's "id" field and the current value of `start_id`. The updated JSON data is written to a temporary file named `tmp.json`, and then that file is renamed to the original file name using the `mv` command.
7. `echo "Updated $file with start_id=$start_id"`: This displays a message indicating that the file has been updated with the current value of `start_id`.
8. `start_id=$((start_id + 10))`: This increments the `start_id` variable by 10, so that the next file that is updated will have a higher "id" value.
9. `done`: This marks the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).